# RPG file using dynamic SQL fails to display data to display file

Tags: sql, db2, rpgle, embedded-sql

I wrote dynamic SQL to show information about a student whose student ID is entered when a user enters an ID, the information on the next screen in the display file has no data. All the fields come from WUSTDP and I have not gotten to the part where I use the other files/tables.

I was expecting to see information about the student including address, phone number, ssn, name, and email

**display file**

```
                                            INDARA
     A                                      CA12(12 'CANCEL')
     A                                      CA03(03 'EXIT')
     A          R STUDSEL
     A                                  1  2'Lab 12'
     A                                  1 30'Wibaux University'
     A                                  2 23'Student Registration aplication'
     A                                  1 71DATE
     A                                  6 23'Student Number'
     A                                  9 23'Type value, then enter.'
     A                                 15  3'F3=Exit  F12=Cancel'
     A            STUDNT         9D  I  6 40
     A          R DISPSTUD
     A                                  1  2'Lab 12'
     A                                  1 30'Wibaux University'
     A                                  2 23'Student Registration aplication'
     A                                  1 71DATE
     A                                  3 10'Student ID:'
     A                                  4 10'Student Name:'
     A                                  5 10'Address:'
     A                                  6 10'Phone:'
     A                                  7 10'Email:'
     A                                 16  4'F3=Exit  F12=Cancel'
     A            STUDNAME      36   B  4 30
     A            ADDRESS       39   B  5 30
     A            PHONE     R        B  6 30REFFLD(STUDREC/PHONE FLIGHT2023/WUS-
     A                                      TDP)
     A            SEMAIL    R        B  7 30REFFLD(STUDREC/SEMAIL FLIGHT2023/WU-
     A                                      STDP)
     A                                  9 10'Section Number'
     A            SECTION   R        B  9 30REFFLD(SECREC/SECTION FLIGHT2023/WU-
     A                                      SCTP)
     A            STUSSN    R        B  3 30REFFLD(STUDREC/STUSSN FLIGHT2023/WU-
     A                                      STDP)

     A          R REGCOMPLT
     A                                  1  2'Lab 12'
     A                                  1 30'Wibaux University'
     A                                  2 23'Student Registration aplication'
     A                                  1 71DATE
     A                                  3 10'Student ID:'
     A                                  4 10'Student Name:'
     A                                  5 10'Address:'
     A                                  6 10'Phone:'
     A                                  7 10'Email:'
     A                                  9 10'Class Information'
     A                                 10 10'Dept:'
     A                                 10 20'Course:'
     A                                 10 35'Section:'
     A                                 10 52'Credits:'
     A                                 11 10'Meets:'

     A                                 16  4'F3=Exit  F12=Cancel'
     A            STUSSN    R        B  3 30REFFLD(STUDREC/STUSSN FLIGHT2023/WU-
     A                                      STDP)
     A            STUDNAME      36   B  4 30
     A            ADDRESS       39   B  5 30
     A            PHONE     R        B  6 30REFFLD(STUDREC/PHONE FLIGHT2023/WUS-
     A                                      TDP)
     A            SEMAIL    R        B  7 30REFFLD(STUDREC/SEMAIL FLIGHT2023/WU-
     A                                      STDP)
     A            SECTION   R        B  9 30REFFLD(SECREC/SECTION FLIGHT2023/WU-
     A                                      SCTP)
     A            DEPT      R        B 10 15REFFLD(CRSREC/DEPT FLIGHT2023/WUCRS-
     A                                      P)
     A            COURSE    R        B 10 28REFFLD(CRSREC/COURSE FLIGHT2023/WUC-
     A                                      RSP)
     A            CREDIT    R        B 10 60REFFLD(CRSREC/CREDIT FLIGHT2023/WUC-
     A                                      RSP)
     A            SECTION1  R        B 10 44REFFLD(SECREC/SECTION FLIGHT2023/WU-
     A                                      SCTP)
     A            SECDAY    R        B 11 17REFFLD(SECREC/SECDAY FLIGHT2023/WUS-
     A                                      CTP)
     A            SECTIM    R        B 11 21REFFLD(SECREC/SECTIM FLIGHT2023/WUS-
     A                                      CTP)
     A                                 13 10'Press enter to confirm enrolment'
     A          R REGMSG
     A                                  1  2'Lab 12'
     A                                  1 30'Wibaux University'
     A                                  2 23'Student Registration aplication'
     A                                  1 71DATE
     A                                 11 25'Registration completed'
     A                                 12 21'You have been added to the section-

     A                                      .'
     A                                 18 13'Press Enter to continue'
     A                                 20  1'F3=Exit   F12 = Cancel'
     A          R ERROR
     A                                  1 28'ERROR'
     A                                  4 14'oNE OR MORE THINGS WERE ENTERED IN-
     A                                      CORRECTLY'
     A                                 10  2'F3=EXIT   F12=CANCEL'
     A          R RECORD1

     A*%%RS+<record-sequences>
     A*%%RS+ <sequence name="Untitled">
     A*%%RS+  <device type="display" width="80" height="24" />
     A*%%RS+ </sequence>
     A*%%RS </record-sequences>
```

**SQLRPGLE file**

```
**FREE
//--------------------------------------------------------- WUSTDP, WUSCTP, WUCRSP, and WUENRLP
// AUTHOR: VICTOR HERNANDEZ
// DATE: 3/8/2024
// PROGRAM NAME: LAB12RPG
// PURPOSE: ALLOW A STUDENT TO INTERACT WITH A DISPLAY FILE IN ORDER TO SIGN UP FOR CLASSES
// --------------------------------------------------------FILES
//ctl-opt option(*nodebugio:*srcstmt) ;

DCL-F LAB12SCRN1 WORKSTN INDDS(INDICATORS);
DCL-F WUSTDP  USAGE(*OUTPUT:*INPUT);
DCL-F WUSCTP  USAGE(*OUTPUT:*INPUT);
DCL-F WUCRSP  USAGE(*OUTPUT);
DCL-F WUENRLP USAGE(*OUTPUT);
//---------------------------------------------------------VARIABLES
Dcl-ds Indicators len(99);
  Exit      Ind pos(3);    //Exit
  Cancel    Ind pos(12);   //Cancel
  FKey      Ind pos(25);   //vldcmdkey
  StudIDErr Ind pos(30);   //Student ID error
  SecNumErr Ind pos(35);   //Section number error
  Enter     Ind pos(40);   //Enter

END-DS;
//---------------------------------------------------------VARIABLES
dcl-s   SqlString char(100);
//---------------------------------------------------------DATA STRUCTURES
dcl-ds StudInfo;
  xStussn   Zoned(9:0);
  xStudname char(36);
  xAddress  char(39);
  xPhone    zoned(10:0);
  xSEmail   char(30);
END-DS;

dcl-ds ClassInfo;
  XDept    char(3);     //WUCRSP
  XCourse  zoned (3:0); //WUCRSP & WUSTDP
  XSection zoned(5:0);  //WUSCTP & WUENRLP
  XSecday  char(3);     //WUSCTP
  xsectim  zoned(4:0);  // WUSCTP
  XCredit  zoned(1:0);  //WUCRSP
END-DS;
//---------------------------------------------------------Main


  Exfmt Studsel;

  SqlString = 'SELECT STUSSN, (SFNAME CONCAT " " CONCAT SLNAME),  '+
    '(STREET CONCAT " " CONCAT CITY CONCAT " " CONCAT STATE),     '+
    'PHONE, SEMAIL                                                '+
    'FROM WUSTDP                                                  '+
    'WHERE STUSSN = ?';

  clear StudInfo;

  EXEC SQL PREPARE CUR FROM :SqlString;
  //exec sql EXECUTE CUR USING :StudInfo;

  EXEC SQL DECLARE STUDCUR CURSOR FOR CUR;

  EXEC SQL OPEN STUDCUR using :Studnt;

  EXEC SQL FETCH STUDCUR INTO :StudInfo;

  STUSSN = XSTUSSN;
  STUDNAME = XSTUDNAME;
  ADDRESS = XADDRESS;
  PHONE = XPHONE;
  SEMAIL = XSEMAIL;

  Exfmt Dispstud;

Exec SQL close studcur;
*Inlr = *On;
Return;
```

[display file output after entering student id/ssn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsVMy.png)

Answer (score 3):

I would debug the program to see if the fields used by the EXFMT have any data.

If they don't have any data, the problem is probably with the SQL statement. The joblog would have information about any problems with the SQL statement.

In your program, you should be checking whether the SQL statement was successful by checking SQLCODE and SQLSTATE. https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.5?topic=sql-handling-error-return-codes-using-sqlca

Answer (score 2):

I can’t call myself a big specialist in display files, but in my opinion it’s worth doing the following:

- For all record formats, specify the PUTOVR and OVERLAY attributes
- For all fields, specify the OVRDTA attribute

In addition, for the STUDNT field I would set the mode not to I, but to B. And for all other fields (if they are not meant to be changed) - not B, but O

Also, in my opinion, dynamic SQL is not required in this case - it is more resource-intensive. Static SQL is more suitable here.

```
exec SQL declare curGetStudent cursor for
  SELECT STUSSN, 
         (SFNAME CONCAT " " CONCAT SLNAME), 
         (STREET CONCAT " " CONCAT CITY CONCAT " " CONCAT STATE),
         PHONE, 
         SEMAIL
    FROM WUSTDP
   WHERE STUSSN = :Studnt;

exec SQL open curGetStudent;

exec SQL fetch curGetStudent into :StudInfo;
```

Moreover, if the result of the selection is one single record, then a cursor is not required. You can directly

```
exec SQL SELECT STUSSN, 
                (SFNAME CONCAT " " CONCAT SLNAME), 
                (STREET CONCAT " " CONCAT CITY CONCAT " " CONCAT STATE),
                PHONE, 
                SEMAIL 
           INTO :StudInfo
           FROM WUSTDP
          WHERE STUSSN = :Studnt;
```